# Using ggplot2 in R, how can I also print min, q1, mean, median, q3, max values on their respective points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've already been able to print outlier values.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = "", y = wt) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data=. %>% 
            mutate(type=rownames(.)) %>% 
            filter(wt %in% boxplot.stats(wt, coef=1.4)$out),
            aes(label=type,y=wt), 
            nudge_x=0.01, colour="red", size=3, hjust=0) +    
theme_classic()
```

I know the ggplotly function shows this information, but it doesn't allow saving along with the image. @Sparhawk and @CuriousJ presents a similar solution using the boxplot function.

I tried this way but to no avail.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = "", y = wt) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data=. %>% 
            mutate(type=rownames(.)) %>% 
            filter(wt %in% boxplot.stats(wt, coef=1.4)$out),
            aes(label=type,y=wt), 
            nudge_x=0.01,size=3, hjust=0) +  
  geom_text(data=mtcars, aes(
                             label=boxplot.stats(wt)$start,
                             y=boxplot.stats(wt)$start), 
            nudge_x=0.01, size=3, hjust=0) + 
theme_classic()
```

any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no points for the q1 / median / q3 (these are summary statistics, not individual points), but if you want to include the corresponding values on the plot (min, q1, median, q3, max), you could use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

boxplot_labels <- tibble(y = boxplot.stats(mtcars$wt, coef=1.4)$stats,
                                 x = c(1.1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.1)) %>% 
  mutate(labels = paste("\u2190 y =", y))

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = "", y = wt) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data=. %>% 
              mutate(type=rownames(.)) %>% 
              filter(wt %in% boxplot.stats(wt, coef=1.4)$out),
            aes(label=type,y=wt), 
            nudge_x=0.01, colour="red", size=3, hjust=0) +
  geom_text(data = boxplot_labels,
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = labels), color = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso, Regards.